# postgresqlが使えなくなった。

Tags: postgresql

https://bsofsys.com/2023/01/05/postgresql-log/
に従って、再起動を行ったところPostgreSQLに入れなくなってしまいました。

原因は何でしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記！
サービスからpostgresql-x64-12を開始しようとしたところ下記のコメントが出ました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記！２０２３年５月１６日現在
現状のPostgresは上記のサイトを行う前のデフォルトの状態です。

Comment: 質問を [edit] して、環境の情報を付け足していただけないでしょうか。現状だと回答しようとしても第三者が問題を手元で再現しづらいです。

Answer (score 0):

一度アンインストールして、再インストールしました。
再起動に関する問題はまだ解決されていないのですが、恐らく再び同じ現象が起こると思うので、再起動は避けたいと考えております。